# Eclipse plugins jar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

how I can identify which jar from eclipse is calling  when we are running application in a eclipse.

Like is there any process or any code which will give us the particular jar name when we are running one application

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the same as in the About Dialog of Eclipse itself, but for your application. In this case you may simple query the Platform. Like:

```
IBundleGroupProvider[] bundleGroupProviders = Platform.getBundleGroupProviders(); 
for (IBundleGroupProvider bundleProvider : bundleGroupProviders) {
  for (IBundleGroup bundleGroup : bundleProvider.getBundleGroups()) {
    Bundle aSingleBundle = bundleGroup.getBundles();
    // TODO: do something useful with this precious information
  }
}
```

That should give you all the bundles loaded with your application

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a misunderstanding of the Eclipse plugins system. If you are running a single Eclipse application, then this application consists of several hundred plugins, and under normal conditions, a huge number of those are executed at the same time. One just for managing your workspace, one for a certain, another one for another view and so on.